Why is this example of calculating the switching loss of a MOS transistor with an inductive load considered misleading?
I just saw an example of calculating the switching loss of a MOS transistor with an inductive load from this (page 20). Can anyone explain why they said this is misleading here? Are they implying this is just an approximation because it does not consider parasitic capacitances, and these capacitors are non-linear, changing with bias?


Please link to the site on which the slide player can be opened. Who has put all the extra scrawl over the original document. Can we have a link to the original document without all the scrawl please?

@Andyaka I also felt a bit annoyed, but I think that's how slideplayer works—by clicking to move to the next page? I don't know the orginal. I just updated another version.

The document needs provenance i.e. a proper source. Without it, it's just guesswork what they were thinking.

@Andyaka I just found a better version with reference to the author and course, editted above.

I think the document is flawed. I mean why is the title of that page suggesting that the load is inductive when it's clearly and unambiguously resistive. Find your self a better document or ask a question here if you don't understand something but nobody other than the author is going to be able to justify the words used.

Diode losses are explicitly mentioned on slides 19 to 21, if not in words on slide 20 ("hand-drawn addition" to picture assuming the diode ideal).

@Andyaka  The circuit is the classic "clamped inductive load" wrt to the switching device, for the time interval of the switching transition.  I don't think the final R across the output cap is what was being referenced here.   So the title is correct in that regard, however, the word "misleading" is much harder to justify. the slide should have clearly explained why the author thinks this "classical example" is "misleading".

A copy of that same slide (page 20/29) is repeated without scrawl on page 25/29.

The slide seems to be concerned with the dynamics around the instant of switching; L is a constant current source, then, and there is no resistance as such around the MOSFET.

The OP's explanation is as good as any, I reckon.  I can see nothing wrong or "misleading" with the waveforms and calculations presented on this slide provided the following assumptions are accepted:

No parasitic capacitances on any devices.
MOSFET is ideal, with zero conduction loss.
Diode is ideal, ie: has zero forward voltage drop, zero reverse recovery, and zero turn-on time (zero "forward recovery" :-)).

Theoretical switching power loss will start to match real-world measurements more accurately as you start to include more real-world non-idealities into the circuit model, such as parasitic MOSFET capacitances (drain-source, gate-source, and gate-drain), and diode reverse recovery.  Yes, capacitances associated with semi-conductor devices are non-linear (vary with voltage), making simple calculations based on capacitance very difficult, which is why some OEMs specify switching energy loss rather than parasitic capacitances in their datasheets.  This concept is explained on pages 16 to 20 of this publication from Infineon, available here:
https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2254331.pdf
Further, a real-world inductor will have parasitic resistance & capacitance, and a real-world output capacitor will have parasitic inductance and resistance.  All of which contribute to a more complex model that makes accurate predictions of switching loss more challenging.
The course instructor, Robert Erickson, is a well-respected academic and has published many papers.  I would suggest his lecture would explain why this slide has this title.

One more assumption: that switching is Miller limited. This is often not the case in practice, especially considering nonlinear capacitances.  It is the case when Cdg is significant, and furthermore we obtain the waveforms when Cdg and Cds are constant.
